# Jib - Google Container Registry: can't authenticate to the registry with error "Unable to parse json key"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, google-container-registry, jib

I want to push my image to the container registry of google.

The command I'm using is (executed via Gitlab Ci, variables are working, testing it one stage ahead):

```
- mvn compile jib:build -Djib.to.image=$registry 
  -Djib.to.auth.username=_json_key -Djib.to.auth.password=$googleServiceAccount
```

The permissions of the Service Account is 'Storage Object Administration'.

The error: (BTW: the Spring Boot application is working - testing on stage ahead)

```
Containerizing application to eu.gcr.io/(project-id), eu.gcr.io/(project-id):version...
 [WARNING] Base image 'gcr.io/distroless/java:11' does not use a specific image digest - build may not be reproducible
 [INFO] Using credentials from <to><auth> for eu.gcr.io/(project-id)
 [INFO] Getting manifest for base image gcr.io/distroless/java:11...
 [INFO] Building dependencies layer...
 [INFO] Building resources layer...
 [INFO] Building classes layer...
 [INFO] Using base image with digest: sha256:7fc091e8686df11f7bf0b7f67fd7da9862b2b9a3e49978d1184f0ff62cb673cc
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time:  17.432 s
 [INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-08T17:20:30Z
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.5.2:build (default-cli) on project projektarbeit: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'eu.gcr.io/(project-id)' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help: Unauthorized for eu.gcr.io/(project-id): 400 Bad Request
 [ERROR] {"errors":[{"code":"UNKNOWN","message":"Unable to parse json key."}]}
```

As password i tried besides the json file also to parse the key directly beginning with 'MIIEv...'. (without \n and ---BEGIN/END----)

```
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQI
```

I really hope, that somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: Looks like the wrong credentials: `Unauthorized for eu.gcr.io/(project-id): 400 Bad Request` - are you sure you have the correct ones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `$googleServiceAccount` should be the content of the JSON key file (i.e., not a file path), such as

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII...",
  "client_email": "....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/....iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

And of course, the content should be properly quoted/escaped if running on a command line.

As officially [documented](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key), for example, if you were logging in locally with `docker login`, it would be

```
docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://[HOSTNAME]
```

The Google Container Registry (GCR) server is complaining (400 Bad Request, meaning you sent an invalid/unexpected request) because it cannot parse the content of `$googleServiceAccount` as a JSON.

Therefore, I am pretty sure you are not providing the entirety of the JSON content of the key file or something's missing or broken that makes it an invalid JSON structure. Double-check the key file and the variable content.

A common mistake is that `$googleServiceAccount` is a key file path. In that case, this may work:

```
mvn compile jib:build \
  -Djib.to.image=$registry \
  -Djib.to.auth.username=_json_key \
  -Djib.to.auth.password="$( cat $googleServiceAccount )"
```

Note `"$( cat ... )"` to get the properly escaped/quoted JSON content of the file.

Comment: Yeah I thought that to, therefore I even tripple checked the param and json key before I posted here. :)

I think that there is some problem with JIB internally, that it can't handle the json file. But honestly idk.

Comment: I am one of the Jib devs, and I am certain that it is not a Jib issue. Jib doesn't process the string literal given by `jib.to.auth.password` at all. The value will be passed to GCR as-is. And as you mentioned in the other answer, I suspect `$googleServiceAccount` was a file path, not JSON content.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It's way cleaner and working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the build of an own docker image which includes

- Maven
- JDK
- Google SDK.

```
The command:
 - gcloud auth activate-service-account (service-account) --key-file=$googleServiceAccount
 - gcloud auth configure-docker
 - mvn compile jib:build -Djib.to.image=$registry
```

Token is by the way the file, not the key

Comment: In the case where `$googleServiceAccount` is a file path, perhaps this will work: `mvn compile jib:build -Djib.to.image=$registry -Djib.to.auth.username=_json_key -Djib.to.auth.password="$( cat $googleServiceAccount )"`. Note `"$( cat ... )"` to get the JSON content of the file.